# Notification api not working

Tags: html, notifications

I used the html 5 notification api and saved it on my desktop as index.html but the notification api does not work even after clicking the allow option. It does work from demo sites.

Comment: try running it from a local `http` server. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

Answer (score 2):

Notification api will only work if you try running it from localhost, 127.0.0.1 or https in your domain because of security concerns. It saves a service worker file on your browser so that hackers or any man in the middle can easily hack that data if it is not encrypted via SSL. So in live websites you must have SSL certificate but on your local machine you can run this using any server.

Try running it via any server like xampp.

Even after using a server, you cannot get any notification on LAN devices using 192.168.#.# ip if you don't have SSL in your machine. Try openssl for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out. 
http://www.darianshimy.com/blog/2012/08/14/web-notifications-in-chrome-and-safari/

I was also running into same issues when running the up from the file system. Like //file/Desktop la bla.

I then ran it with my local server and it worked...